# Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 27

Tags: compilation-error

I am getting the above error while compiling the below code using Springer journal template available at [Template](https://media.springernature.com/full/springer-cms/rest/v1/content/18782940/data/Download+the+journal+article+template+package)

The MWC is shared below

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences Reference Style
%%%% Standard Packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[center]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-icomp,maxcitenames=1,maxbibnames=9]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%\addbibresource{references.bib}
%%<additional latex packages if required can be included here>
\usepackage[linesnumbered,lined,boxed,commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./images/}}
%Table packages
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 1fil}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\footnotesize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}

%%%%%=============================================================================%%%%

\jyear{2022}

%% as per the requirement new theorem styles can be included as shown below

\raggedbottom
%%\unnumbered% uncomment this for unnumbered level heads

\begin{document}

\title[Article Title]{Article Title}

\author*[1,2]{\fnm{First} \sur{Author}}\email{iauthor@gmail.com}

\author[2,3]{\fnm{Second} \sur{Author}}\email{iiauthor@gmail.com}
\equalcont{These authors contributed equally to this work.}

\author[1,2]{\fnm{Third} \sur{Author}}\email{iiiauthor@gmail.com}
\equalcont{These authors contributed equally to this work.}

\affil*[1]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{100190}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}

\affil[2]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{10587}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}

\affil[3]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{610101}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}

%%==================================%%
%% sample for unstructured abstract %%
%%==================================%%

\abstract{The abstract serves both as a general introduction to the topic and as a brief, non-technical summary of the main results and their implications. Authors are advised to check the author instructions for the journal they are submitting to for word limits and if structural elements like subheadings, citations, or equations are permitted.}


\keywords{keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3, Keyword4}

%%\pacs[JEL Classification]{D8, H51}

%%\pacs[MSC Classification]{35A01, 65L10, 65L12, 65L20, 65L70}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}\label{sec1}

The Introduction section, of referenced text \cite{bib1} expands on the background of the work (some overlap with the Abstract is acceptable). The introduction should not include subheadings.

Springer Nature does not impose a strict layout as standard however authors are advised to check the individual requirements for the journal they are planning to submit to as there may be journal-level preferences. When preparing your text please also be aware that some stylistic choices are not supported in full text XML (publication version), including coloured font. These will not be replicated in the typeset article if it is accepted.

\section{Results}\label{sec2}

Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text.

\section{This is an example for first level head---section head}\label{sec3}

\subsection{This is an example for second level head---subsection head}\label{subsec2}

\subsubsection{This is an example for third level head---subsubsection head}\label{subsubsec2}

Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text. Sample body text.


%% Default %%
%%\input sn-sample-bib.tex%

\end{document}
```

Please help. Threads with similar headings did not solve my problem.

Comment: I can't delve into the code right now but the class seems to be incompatible with `biblatex`.

Comment: As @campa says, the class uses `natbib` and so you can't load `biblatex`. Besides also `caption`, `subcaption` and `algorithm2e` are incompatible.

Comment: Ok, as a beginner , I don't know how to substitute these packages.